# D3: .transition() not working with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, d3.js

I'm busy plotting a bar chart using D3 in Angular4.

```
// Enter Phase
this.chart.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(this.barData)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'bar');

// Update Phase
let bars = this.chart.selectAll('.bar').transition()
  .attr('x', (d) => {return this.x(this.parseTime(d.date.toUpperCase()));})
  .attr('y', (d) => {return this.y(d.point)})
  .attr('width', 15)
  .attr('height', (d) => {return this.charDimensions.height - this.y(d.point);})
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {D3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5);})
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {D3.select(this).style('opacity', 1);})
    .on("click", (d) => {this.barClicked.emit(d);});

// Exit phase
this.chart.selectAll('.bar')
  .data(this.barData)
  .exit().remove();
```

In my plotting method, when I call `animate()` I get an error: `Error: unknown type: mouseover`. Which makes sense, since I'm probably trying to call the `on("<event>")` on a the transition returned by D3, the transition effect is there, however, everything after the transition breaks, i.e: The animation works, but the plotting is broken ofc.

However when I attempt to do the following:

```
// Update Phase
let bars = this.chart.selectAll('.bar');
bars.transition();
bars.attr('x', (d) => {return this.x(this.parseTime(d.date.toUpperCase()));})
  .attr('y', (d) => {return this.y(d.point)})
  .attr('width', 15)
  .attr('height', (d) => {return this.charDimensions.height - this.y(d.point);})
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {D3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5);})
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {D3.select(this).style('opacity', 1);})
    .on("click", (d) => {this.barClicked.emit(d);});
```

No errors occur, but nothing happens, there is no transition effect to the new data set.

Comment: Would it help to add duration? `let bars = this.chart.selectAll('.bar').transition().duration(3000).attr(...`.

Comment: Tried that, no luck @wazz

Comment: @wazz you don't need to set the duration: if there is none, D3 creates a default 250ms duration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here is a confusion between two **different** methods that use the **same** name:

- [*selection*.on(*typenames*[, *listener*])](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_on)
- [*transition*.on(*typenames*[, *listener*])](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_on)

Since you have a transition selection, when you write...

```
.on(...
```

The method expects to see three things (or typenames):

- "start"
- "end"
- "interrupt"

However, "mouseover", "mouseout" or "click" are none of them. And then you get your error...

```
> Uncaught Error: unknown type: mouseover
```

**Solution**:

Bind the event listeners to a regular selection. Then, after that, create your transition selection.

Therefore, in your case, bind all the `on` listeners to the "enter" selection (which, by the way, makes more sense), removing them from the update selection.

Have a look at this little demo. First, I create a regular, enter selection, to which I add the event listener:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    //some attr here
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log(d)
    });
```

Then, I add the transition:

```
bars.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    etc...
```

Hover over the bars to see the "mouseover" working:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [30, 280, 40, 140, 210, 110];
var bars = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 20
  })
  .attr("height", 18)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d)
  });

bars.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 25% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```